# jquery fade in hover image of sprite

Tags: jquery, sprite, fade

like in http://jsfiddle.net/eFLdd/1/ I have ul li navigation based on a sprite image.

There are also hover images. I want a mouseover function for each item that changes the class i.e. nav1hover with a fade out and fade in.

Does anybody has some tips? thx in advance.

Comment: Please fix your image paths in jsFiddle, it will make it clear to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to have both states of the navigation present at the same time, see http://jsfiddle.net/graham/kxpLu/2/ for example.

By creating a simple list for the navigation:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="nav1"><a href=""><span></span></a></li>
    <li class="nav2"><a href=""><span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Which is styled like:

```
.navigation li { 
    background: url(http://blog.grahamlicence.co.uk/jsfiddle/nav.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
}
.navigation li.nav2 { background-position: -82px 0; }
.navigation li span { 
    background: url(http://blog.grahamlicence.co.uk/jsfiddle/nav.jpg) no-repeat 0 -56px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
}
.navigation li.nav2 span { background-position: -82px -56px;}
```

What I've done here is add the normal state of the link to the `<span>` element and the hover state at the background of the `<li>`.

The script then fades the normal state on hover, like so:

```
$(".navigation li a").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("span").stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 300);
}, function () {
    $(this).children("span").animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 400);
});
```